# vfs_read returns -EFAULT for a file opened with DirectIO (code running in kernel space)

Tags: c, linux, kernel

So I want to simulate a pread (with DIRECT_IO) in Linux kernel space. So I use kmalloc to allocate a piece of memory in kernel space and did a vfs_read. vfs_read want to put the data in a user_space buffer. I bypass that check by doing set_fs(KERNEL_DS). Overall my code looks like:

```
temp = (char*)kmalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL);

mm_segment_t old_fs;

old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

ret = vfs_read(file, temp, count, &pos);

set_fs(old_fs);
kfree(tmp)
```

Now the problem is, the above method only works well without DIRECT_IO. With DIRECT_IO, vfs_read would return -EFAULT.

Can someone help me so I can know which restriction in DIRECT_IO is violated? I know that both count and pos are 4kb aligned.

Comment: Could it be something as simple as memory alignment?  direct-io usually requires block or page alignment, whereas kmalloc may not give you that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even after I aligned the memory buffer, I am still getting the -EFAULT.

Comment: It is probably the nature of DIRECT_IO. DIO wants to avoid keeping stuff in kernel memory, and thats what I am trying to do here.

Comment: The code here is called by a systemtap probe on a syscall. Thats why the code is running in kernel space. By the way, Do you know any way to allocate some memory in user_space from a systemtap probe? I think being able to get a buffer in user_space can solve all those issues I got from kernel

Comment: One very dumb way I have thought about is, write a c program and all it does is a single malloc(). And somehow I keep that c program continuously running. At the same time Systemtap probe get triggered from that malloc call and stap can record the returned memory address... This might work but I really need some better way to allocate memory in user space from systemtap probe

Comment: Maybe you need to take a new look at the choice of approach.   http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhyWritingFilesFromKernelIsBad